# Unable to click on "Documents" tab from <div class = "TabContent TitleTabContainer"> through vba code

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdSHow As Long) As Long

Sub Pulldata_BI_Launch()
CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer    
Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument    
Dim elems As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection    
Dim attr As MSHTML.IHTMLBodyElement    

'Make internet explorer visible    
IE.Visible = True    
IE.Navigate "https://*************** "    
ShowWindow IE.hwnd, 3

'Wait for page loads fully    
Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE    
Loop

'Collect webpage opened in variable    
Set htmldoc = IE.document

'Click on Documents tab from container    
Set elems = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("a")    
    Set attr = elems.Item    
    For Each attr In elems    
    If (attr.Item("title") = "Documents") Then    
    attr.Click    
    Exit For    
    End If    
    Next attr    
End Sub
```

---

I'm looking to click on **Documents** tab next to **Home** tab through code but unable to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Following is screenprint for inspect element of Documents tab button:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEC7A.jpg)

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on the line `attr.Click`, do you hit it?

Comment: Instead of getting all element by tag name "a", try a CSS selector `a[title='Documents']`. That should get you the one you need without the loop then just click on it

Comment: @ matteo NNZ - Yes in the break point mode when I debug it reaching to attr.Click but initialising with null value

Comment: @ JeffC - Thanks for the quick suggestion & I'll surely give a try with a CSS selector today.

Answer (score 0):

I try to test your code which is giving Type mismatch error at 2 places.

I suggest you to make a test with code below which is able to click that Documents tab.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
<script>
function abc()
{
alert("hi....");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="TabContent TitleTabContainer">
<a title="Documents" class="TabTitle" role="tab" style="width:auto;" onclick="abc()" href="javascript:void(null);">Documents</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

VBA code:

```
Sub demo()
Dim ie As Object
Dim form As Variant, button As Variant
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


With ie
.Visible = True
.Navigate ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\48.html")

While ie.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Wend

For Each l In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If l.Title = "Documents" Then
        l.Click
        Exit For
        End If

    Next

End With
End Sub
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

Further, You can try to refer the code and try to modify it as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using a css attribute = value selector

```
ie.document.querySelector("[title=Documents]").click
```

You could additionally add in the class:

```
ie.document.querySelector(".TabTitle[title=Documents]").click
```

---

Before the click make sure you have a proper page load wait:

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

Comment: Did the above meet with any success?